# Cut on a higher level in Prolog

Tags: prolog, prolog-cut

Say you have a program:

```
a(X) :- b(X).
a(X) :- c(X).

b(a).
b(b) :- !,fail.
b(c).
c(a).
```

A query `a(X)` will return `A=a; X=a`. I'm looking however for a mechanism where the cut (`!`) does not only prevent one from further executing predicates in the same node of the execution tree, but will simply backtrack to a certain level.

---

**Virtual cut (`?`)**

For instance if that operator would be `?`,

the program:

```
a(X) :- ?,b(X).
a(X) :- c(X).

b(a).
b(b) :- !,fail.
b(c).
c(a).
```

Would result in `X=a`, because it first binds with `b(a)` (this `X=a`), next attempts to bind with `b(b)` and fails, and since `?` was placed on the level of `a(X)`, this "virtual cut" is activated as well preventing `a(X)` from taking the next branch.

In case of the following program however:

```
a(X) :- ?,b(X).
a(X) :- c(X).

b(a).
b(b).
b(c).
c(a).
```

The result should be `X=a; X=b; X=c; X=a.` since the cut is never activated underneath the `a(X)` SLD-tree.

The question is wether such virtual cut exists.

Comment: So, um… what is the question?

Comment: By the way, in your first example with `?`, an `X=b` binding is never forged because `b(b)` always fails. Thinking of predicate definition as `goal :- <steps-to-prove-goal>` it's hard for me to see your semantics. I bet you could implement it with a meta-interpreter (apologies to Richard O'Keefe) but I think you'll find it difficult to achieve coherent semantics if you create bindings upon failure sometimes.

Comment: @DanielLyons: The question is whether such virtual cut exists. And indeed `X=b` never bind. "attempts to bind" is probably a better expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is called 'ancestral cut', see the [documentation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=ancestral-cut) page. [Searching](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=prolog%20ancestor%20%20cut&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#channel=fs&q=prolog%20ancestral%20%20cut) for it yields a fair amount of answers.

In summary, I think exception handling (see [throw](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=throw/1)/1, ISO standardized) it's the true alternative to this older tool.

Comment: Exception handling is a very nice solution to this problem. What is the expected overhead that comes with this solution in (swi-)Prolog?

Comment: I think it's lightweight... I've seen it used to clean-up constrained variables store, for instance...

Comment: The common name is *ancestor cut*. Don't know where SWI go that odd terminology from. In any case, it is definitely better to go with catch/throw.

Comment: @false: I initially posted exactly that, but after looking at doc page, I changed it...